# Grabbing longitude and Latitude value from a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, dictionary, geolocation

Please how do i get the value of "lat" and "lon" outside their function to use else where on the page.

```
   navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(handle_geolocation_query,handle_errors);  

    function handle_errors(error)  
    {  
        switch(error.code)  
        {  
            case error.PERMISSION_DENIED: alert("user did not share geolocation data");  
            break;  
            case error.POSITION_UNAVAILABLE: alert("could not detect current position");  
            break;  
            case error.TIMEOUT: alert("retrieving position timed out");  
            break;  
            default: alert("unknown error");  
            break;  
        }  
    }  
   function handle_geolocation_query(position){  
        var lat = (position.coords.latitude);
       var lon = (position.coords.longitude); 

    }
```

What i am trying to do is to get the longitude and latitude of a device and pass it is as a parameter to query and database, also use that same value for other things. I cant figure out how to go about it.
Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: It would help to tag the language!

Comment: Thanks @Steve, have done that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing came my mind (at this late hour :D) is something like this:

- declare a variable outside your handlers, let's say:

  var coords = {};
- then in your 'handle_geolocation_query' handler, trigger an event that gives you an ideea that your position is ready, assuming you're using jQuery:

  $(coords).trigger('positionReady', position);
- after that, everywhere you need those coordinates, listen for your custom 'positionReady' event, and do your job:

  $(coords).on('positionReady', function(e, position) {
      console.log(position);
  });

This will help you to avoid 'spaghetti code', but in the same time, you need to 'think' asynchronously, and maybe using callbacks the (right) way you need.

Comment: Thank you, i am going to try it, i will update you of the out come

Comment: Hello @Nicolae i tried your suggestion but it is returning undefined when i alert it

Comment: It's returning undefined because the alert it's executing before handle_geolocation_query will give you a value.