# Assigning latitude and longitude as variables for global use

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, geolocation, latitude-longitude

How do i get the longitude and latitude of this JavaScript code as variables for global use.  i have tried it several times but not working.

```
 navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(handle_geolocation_query,handle_errors);  

    function handle_errors(error)  
    {  
        switch(error.code)  
        {  
            case error.PERMISSION_DENIED: alert("user did not share geolocation data");  
            break;  
            case error.POSITION_UNAVAILABLE: alert("could not detect current position");  
            break;  
            case error.TIMEOUT: alert("retrieving position timed out");  
            break;  
            default: alert("unknown error");  
            break;  
        }  
    }  
   function handle_geolocation_query(position){  
    }
```

I am using it in a Jquery Mobile and PhoneGap app. Any help will be very much appreciated, thank you

Per the answer giving so far this what i have

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
var latitude, longitude;

     navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(handle_geolocation_query,handle_errors);  

    function handle_errors(error)  
    {  
        switch(error.code)  
        {  
            case error.PERMISSION_DENIED: alert("user did not share geolocation data");  
            break;  
            case error.POSITION_UNAVAILABLE: alert("could not detect current position");  
            break;  
            case error.TIMEOUT: alert("retrieving position timed out");  
            break;  
            default: alert("unknown error");  
            break;  
        }  
    }  
   function handle_geolocation_query(position){  
   latitude = (position.coords.latitude);
   longitude = (position.coords.longitude); 
}
alert(latitude, longitude);     
 });
```

When i alert it it returns "undefined"

This is the html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
   <title>Untitled Document</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
  <link href="http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/default.css" rel="stylesheet"     type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/gas-script.js"></script>
 </head>

<body>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition:

```
var latitude, longitude;
```

Inside handle_geolocoation_query(position):

```
latitude = position.coords.latitude;
longitude = position.coords.longitude;
```

Makes:

```
var latitude, longitude;
$(document).ready(function(){
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(handle_geolocation_query,handle_errors);
    } else {
        alert('Device probably not ready.');
    }
});
function handle_errors(error) {  
    // error handling here
}
function handle_geolocation_query(position){  
    latitude = (position.coords.latitude);
    longitude = (position.coords.longitude); 
    onPositionReady();
}
function onPositionReady() {
    alert(latitude, longitude);
    // proceed
}
```

Comment: @RonaldK, thank you  i tried your answer but the variables are return undefined when alert or console.log

Comment: Which variables? latitude/longitude or position.coords? And when are you testing them?

Comment: Oh wait, you've asked the same question and got an OK answer over here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18883252/grabbing-longitude-and-latitude-value-from-a-function

Comment: $(coords).on('positionReady', function(e, position) {  IT WORKS WHEN I PUT MY CODE HERE }); But outside here it does not work

Comment: Concerning your question latitude or longitude returns "undefined"

Comment: handle_geolocation_query is a callback method, meaning it doesn't do anything until getCurrentPosition finishes. So you can only use latitude and longitude after handle_geolocation_query has been called.

Comment: I have updated my question with answers you have provided so far. please kindly check and see where i am getting it wrong.

Comment: I've updated my answer with an example.

Comment: Does that mean that i will have to wrap any script that will be using the latitude and longitude with this function onPositionReady() {
  MY CODE FOR PASSING LATITUDE AND LONGITUDE TO THE SERVER WILL GO HERE 
}

Comment: Yes. Or in handle_geolocation_query: I only added onPositionReady to show that the variables are available globally.

Comment: Thank you, this answers it. You have done me good may God bless you.

Answer (score 0):

In below mentioned code, lat, lng should be available globally in current file,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var lat, lng;
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(handle_geolocation_query,handle_errors);  
function handle_geolocation_query(position){  
    lat = position.coords.latitude;    
    lng =  position.coords.longitude; 
}  
});
```

Comment: thank you i tried your answer but the variables are return undefined when alert or console.log